# On Facebook - changing SMS message when selling items

Tags: facebook

When user buys something from a Facebook application by SMS, he/she receives a message encouraging to buy this item - is this possible to change the contents of this message?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you make a request call through SMS, based on the content, it replies bacl from the list of avaiable responses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Right now I making a call to FB.ui (javascript SDK) with method:pay, action:purchaseitem and an url to a product.